# What are the minimum necessary command line arguments to build a structured mh_bundle on MacOSX?

Tags: xcode, macos, bundle, qt-creator, mach

When I use Xcode to build a bundle library the output is a structured directory with the format bundlename.bundle where inside is a Contents dir, with a Info.plist, and a MacOS dir with the bundle file inside.

I want to know to build this same output without the need for Xcode. I want to understand the necessary steps to achieve it in order to replicate this behavior on QtCreator using a .pro file.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In order to build a `MH_BUNDLE` all you need to do is pass the `-bundle` argument to `clang` in place of `-dynamiclib`.

**Example**

Library (bundle) file source (`t.c`)

```
int add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

Test file source (`m.c`)

```
int add(int a, int b);

int main()
{
    return add(5, 7);
}
```

Create bundle

```
$ clang -bundle -o t.bundle t.c
```

Check if it is a bundle using `file`

```
$ file t.bundle
t.bundle: Mach-O 64-bit bundle x86_64
```

Check if it is a `MH_BUNDLE` using `clang`

```
$ clang -c m.c -o m.o && clang -o m m.o t.bundle
ld: can't link with bundle (MH_BUNDLE) only dylibs (MH_DYLIB) file 't.bundle' for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```